# Why does this word have the registered trademark symbol ® on it?

Tags: words, symbols

On the weather app on my phone, the word 体感温度 has a ® next to it.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: Japanese Screen]

And here's the corresponding shot in English:

[image]

Am I correct in believing that what is really trademarked is just the English "REALFEEL", and not the Japanese?  If so, why keep the ® in the Japanese (and presumably other languages') translation?

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with the language (only with poor localisation efforts). Unless you have elements showing otherwise, I think this should be closed...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with diamond dave that this is about localization and technology more than it is about Japanese

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is most likely a coding mistake.  When products are internationalized, strings in the code are changed depending on the locale of the user.  In this case, their template is something like

```
"%s\u00AE:"
```

where %s is the localized string. \u00AE is ®.  They obviously haven't filed a trademark on 体感温度, but rather some formula they use that is different from actual windchill/heat index, which they named RealFeel in English.